# How to prepend to order clause with scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Is there any way to prepend to the existing `order` section of an active record query?

I the following associations defined on my `Location` model:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :location_parking_locations, -> { by_votes }
  has_many :parking_locations, through: :location_parking_locations
end
```

In the `LocationParkingLocation` model, the `by_votes` scope is defined:

```
class LocationParkingLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :parking_location
  scope :by_votes, -> { order("upvotes - downvotes ASC, upvotes + downvotes DESC, id ASC") }
end
```

I would like to add a scope to the `ParkingLocation` model that adds an additional scope to the query, but I want that scope to be prepended to the existing `order` section of the query. The scope looks like this:

```
class ParkingLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :location_parking_locations
  has_many :locations, through: :location_parking_locations
  scope :with_pending, -> { order(creation_pending: :desc) }
end
```

My hope is to call `location.parking_locations.with_pending`, and get back a collection of parking_locations, ordered by votes, but with any `pending` parking locations at the beginning of the collection. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Since a scope is a lambda, you can use arguments, for example:

```
scope :your_scope, -> (sort_order = :desc) { order(name: sort_order) }
```

Just set it up as you need and call it with a (possibly optional) argument:

```
your_model.your_scope(:desc)
```